# Is it possible to print a single item from a dictionary on multiple lines?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a script that lets me look up keywords for all the notes I have on that key word. Right now it's all stored in a dictionary.

I was wonder if I could take

```
notes = {'ban': 'BAN: is the account number, Other relative information, More information'}
```

I want the result that is being printed to show up like

```
BAN: is the account number
Other relative information
More information
```

Right now all the information shows up in one big string. Could I use \n within the dictionary to print out information in separate lines?

So far my code looks like:
    ####################################################################################
    ''' Goal = quick access list of notes that I can add to or remove from as needed.'''
    '''    Note: this script is designed for python 3.2+ check converted elements    '''
    ####################################################################################

```
notes = {
    'ban': 'BAN: is the account number, Other relative information, More information', 'test': 'next def of keyword'
    }

switch = True

def note_finder(word):
        print ('Type one of the following keywords','\n','ban','\n','test','\n','test2','\n', 'Or type exit to close')
        choice2 = input('--> ').lower()
        if choice2 == 'exit':
            print ('Exiting Function')
            switch = True
        elif choice2 in notes:
            print (notes[choice2])
        else:
            print ("Not a Keyword")

while switch == True:
    print ('Type one of the following options:','\n','1','\n','No other options at this time.')
    choice1 = int(input('--> '))
    if choice1 < 1 or choice1 > 1:
        print ("Not an option")
    else:
        switch = False
        note_finder(input)
```

Comment: "Could I use `'\n'`?" Yes, you certainly can as it's a regular character, just like those you see in this comment and your question.

Comment: Another option would be `string.split()` on the dictionary values

Comment: Ya I figured that out. I was trying to format it like the print comment is formatted but the commas were messing it up. I did end up figuring it out thought thanks.

Comment: @downshift 
How would I use string.split() I have not used that modifier before. I am still new to python.

Comment: @BaconTech something like `for val in notes.values()[0].split(','): print val`. docs: [str.split()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

Comment: @downshift so the .split() modifier will move the string to the next line before or after the ','.

Comment: @BaconTech, sorry I should have explained better. `str.split()` returns a `list` of strings. From the `split()` docs: `If sep is not specified or is None, any whitespace string is a separator and empty strings are removed from the result`. `str.split(',')` tells it to split on commas, and removes the commas. Giving the same output you showed in the question: `BAN: is the account number <newline>
 Other relative information <newline>
 More information<newline>`

Comment: Or similarly, you can use the dictionary key to get the string, like user1753919 did in his answer: `for val in notes['ban'].split(','): print val`, same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I was having problems with the quotes.

In order to print info to each line you just need to add \n in the quoted text where you want the next line to start.

```
notes = {
    # 'ban': 'BAN: is the account number\n# Other relative information\n# More information',
}
```

here is the result from the code with the \n usage.

```
Type one of the following options: 
 1 
 No other options at this time.
--> 1
Type one of the following keywords 
 ban 
 test 
 test2 
 Or type exit to close
--> ban
# BAN: is the account number
# Other relative information
# More information
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print notes['ban'].replace(', ','\n')
```